# grails login using sql query

Tags: java, sql, grails, groovy, gsp

I am working on grails and I am new to it. I need to login using sql query in grails. Please help me. Here is my view page, controller and domain class.

**login.gsp**

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="layout"content="main"/>
        <g:set var="entityName" value="ProjectTracker Login" />
        <title><g:message code="projectTracker login" args="[entityName]" /></title>
      </head>
      <body>

        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri:"/")}"></a></li>
            <li><g:link class="list" action="logout">Logout</g:link></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="create-endUser" class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
           <h1>Login</h1>


                <g:form action="authenticate" >
                    <fieldset class="form">
                        <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: endUserInstance, field: 'userName', 'error')} ">
                            <label for="userName">
                                <g:message code="endUser.userName.label" default="User Name" />

                            </label>
                            <g:textField name="userName" value="${endUserInstance?.userName}"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: endUserInstance, field: 'password', 'error')} ">
                            <label for="password">
                                <g:message code="endUser.password.label" default="Password" />

                            </label>
                            <g:field type="password" name="password" value="${endUserInstance?.password}"/>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="buttons">
                        <g:submitButton name="login" class="save" value="Login" />
                    </fieldset>
                </g:form>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

my domain class

**Testuser.groovy**

```
class Testuser {

     String userName
        String password
        String fullName
        String toString(){
            "${fullName}"
        }
    static constraints = {
        fullName();
        userName(unique:true);
        password(password:true);
    }
}
```

my controller is

**TestuserController.groovy**

```
import groovy.sql.*
   def index()
{
    redirect(action:"login")
}
 def login={ }
     def authenticate={


     def username_log = parmas.userName
     def password_log = parmas.password
        def results 
         Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def joining = sql.rows("SELECT user_name,password from user where user_name=username_log and password=password_log")
        {
             results << it.toRowResult()
        }
        results
          if (joining != null) {
            results = sql.eachRow()
            redirect(action:"login")
        }
        else {
            redirect(action:"login")
        }
```

this is my code for simple login using sql query and I am getting error like

```
URI
/login/testuser/authenticate
Class
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
No such property: parmas for class: login.test.TestuserController Possible solutions: params
```

Comment: It's `params` not `parmas`. The error message literally tells you exactly this.

Comment: I know this isn't the question, but please read a book on clean code like Bob Martin's Clean Code. There are just so many issues with this code. Why name the variables `username_log' and `password_log`? Why the inconsistency between `username` and `params.userName`? Why is there no space between `def login = { }` but two lines after `def authenticate = {`? Why do you assign `sql.eachRow()` to `results` and never use it? Why do you mix curly braces on a new line with curly braces on the same line? Take some pride in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not `parmas` but `params`.

You want to implement login without using spring security ?

By the way the SQL query should be like this

```
"SELECT user_name,password from user where user_name=$username_log and password=$password_log"
```

You forgot $

Comment: okie.I did so.i need to pass sql query and not the grails default querying method.Just like the method we use in struts framework

Comment: @user1776641 use a security plugin

Comment: now i passed the sql query in the correct manner as you said.Again an exception is araising.The error is groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException.   Line | Method
->>   16 | doCall    in TestuserController.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    200 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread...please help me.

Comment: paste the complete error. Which property is missing?

Comment: You need to escape your SQL to avoid SQL injection: `def joining = sql.rows("SELECT user_name, password from user where user_name = ? and password = ?", [username_log, password_log])`.

Comment: exceptions are                                                 Around line 16 of grails-app\controllers\login\test\TestuserController.groovy                                  def username_log = params.userName
     def password_log = params.password
        def results 
         Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
      def joining = sql.rows("SELECT user_name, password from user where user_name = ? and password = ?", [username_log, password_log])
      // String employee = "SELECT user_name,password from user where user_name=username_log and password=password_log"
       {

Comment: Around line 200 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java                 if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cacheOperations)) {
    log.debug("No cacheable annotation found for {}:{} {}",
      new Object[] { request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
   }

Comment: Around line 63 of AbstractFilter.java                            try {
   // NO_FILTER set for RequestDispatcher forwards to avoid double gzipping
   if (filterNotDisabled(request)) {
    doFilter(request, response, chain);
   }
   else {
    chain.doFilter(req, res);